# jQuery toggleClass targeting correct element

Tags: jquery

Trying to learn jQuery, and toggleClass specifically.

Goal: load a div with a set height and hide the overflow... click an element to show the entire div. Like an accordion, but the top part of the content shows... clicking reveals the rest.

Here's the jQuery (jQuery not $ since I'm working in WPress)...

```
jQuery('.openup').click(function() {
    jQuery('.clip').toggle();
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('clipactive');
    return false;
});
```

Here's my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5u141gL/)

I need help understanding two things:

1. Why is the class 'clipactive' getting added to the clicked element? Doesn't 'this' refer to 'clip' in the line above it? How do I get it to target? Sibling()>?
2. Why does 'clip' get an inline style 'display:none' when I toggle the class?

Is that related to 'this' not being targeted correctly?

Comment: `jQuery(this)` refers to `jQuery('.openup')`, the element that was clicked.

Comment: `this` refers to the element you bound the `click` handler to, in this case that would be `.openup`. `clip` gets `display: none;` because you're calling `toggle()` on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As stated in the comments, `jQuery(this)` refers to the clicked element.
2. The `jQuery('.clip').toggle();` will toggle the `.clip` class, which means it will display or hide the element, whichever one it isn't. So, it will change from `display:none;` to hide it, and `display:block;` to show it.

I think this is the code you want:

```
jQuery('.openup').click(function() {
    jQuery('.clip').toggle();
    jQuery('.clip').toggleClass('clipactive');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Once I removed the toggle() I got what I needed.

Comment: "The jQuery('.clip').toggle(); will toggle the .clip class" This statement isn't quiet correct, it toggles the display of the element it's triggered on. Basically it toggles `display:none`.

Comment: @subhaze Yes, you are correct it won't toggle the class, but I think I cleared it up when I said it will display or hide the element. I should have said "will toggle the elements with the .clip class", but I think he go the point.

Comment: Definitely, was just suggesting you might edit that part is all.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why is the class 'clipactive' getting added to the clicked element? Doesn't 'this' refer to 'clip' in the line above it? How do I get it
>      to target? Sibling()>?

`this` refers to the element that *click was bound to*.

I say 'bound to' because you could have a `<span>` as a child of `.openup` that was clicked, but `this` would not refer to the `<span>`, it would refer to `.openup` since that's what you bound the event to. A bit more info on event handling can be found at https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/

You could get reference to `.clip` a few different ways, below I'll show code to use a `data-` so you can define a selector to what element you want to target:

HTML:

```
<div class="openup" data-target=".clip">Lorem Ipsum </div>
<div class="clip">...</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('.openup').click(function() {
    var target = $($(this).data('target'));
    target.toggleClass('clipactive');
    return false;
});
```

`$(this).data('target')` (this refers to the element clicked) grab the value of `data-target` which is the class we're wanting to target and then we wrap it with `$()` so that jQuery will grab the element by the selector provided `$($(this).data('target'));` and we can now toggle the class.

> 2. Why does 'clip' get an inline style 'display:none' when I toggle the class?

This isn't because of `toggleClass`, it's because you're toggling the element in and out of view `jQuery('.clip').toggle();` that line is not the same as `toggleClass`

**updated jsfiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/b5u141gL/1/

---

**.toggle()** http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

*Display or hide the matched elements.*

**.data()** https://api.jquery.com/data/

*Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.*

Comment: Thanks not only for your answer, but for all the extra info! One of my problems was not noticing the toggle vs. toggleClass difference.